# Does not work Context Menus in cog - Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I wanted to create a context menu in my bot. For example, he took the documentation [code](https://I%20wanted%20to%20create%20a%20context%20menu%20in%20my%20bot.%20For%20example,%20he%20took%20the%20documentation%20code.%20But%20when%20the%20code%20was%20launched%20in%20the%20console%20the%20following%20error%20appeared:).

```py
@app_commands.context_menu(name='react')
async def react_(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, message: discord.Message):
    await interaction.response.send_message('Very cool message!', ephemeral=True)
```

But when the code was launched in the console, the following error appeared:`TypeError: context menus cannot be defined inside a class`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the decorator to create a context menu in Cogs, as explained by Danny [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/7823#issuecomment-1086830458).

The quick way to create them in cogs is to create them by using the `app_commands.ContextMenu` class. Like so:

```py
class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot) -> None:
        self.bot = bot
        self.ctx_menu = app_commands.ContextMenu(
            name='Cool Command Name',
            callback=self.my_cool_context_menu, # set the callback of the context menu to "my_cool_context_menu"
        )
        self.bot.tree.add_command(self.ctx_menu) # add the context menu to the tree

    async def my_cool_context_menu(self, interaction, message):
        ...
```

You can check out Danny's explanation for more information.